# How to create tables in multiple databases using Django models.py

Tags: database, django, django-models, multi-database

I would like to create table "A" in one database (assume in SQL Server 2008) and another table in "B" (My SQL) using models.py through Django.

Both the tables structures "A" and "B" may differ.  I have verified that through router.py can achieve this.

I want to do it without "router.py" file.

Could anyone guide me on this please.

Thanks,
Shiva.

Comment: Why do you want to do it without a router file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [`super`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) in `save()` method.
When you save, it will launch others commands like write in other database.

For example :

You have :

```
class Chair(models.Model) :
  name = models.Charfield(max_length=30)
```

You can implement `save()` def like that :

```
class Chair(models.Model) :
  name = models.Charfield(max_length=30)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    <your cmd here>
    super(Chair, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It could seems impossible like that, but you can use arguments for make anything you want.

Comment: Dear Zulu,can you please explain me in detail with an example